# Gitlab Could not find artifact com.oracle ojdbc8

Tags: oracle, maven, gitlab

I get this error on my gitlab project:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project importparcoursup: Could not resolve dependencies for project nc.unc:importparcoursup:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1
```

Source:
https://gitlab.com/tyvain/parcoursup/-/jobs/94672390

This is normal as oracle jdbc is not available on maven central repo.

Locally I managed to solve it by installing the lib in my local repo with this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Question: how can I solve this problem on gitlab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the build:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar compile
```